# Cucumber MissingTamplate error if view has .haml extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, cucumber

Why is Cucumber gives MissingTamplate error when running test on veiw with index.html.**haml** extension? (Rails 4, Cucumber,Capybara, Haml gems installed. All views is coded with haml markup. All view files in place. When change file name to **index.html.erb** no error raised! Why???)

Searching google to solve plm didn't help

```
ec2-user:~/environment/01-hw-saas/myrottenpotatoes $ cucumber features/AdMovie.feature 
Using the default profile...
Feature: User can manually add movie

  Scenario: Add a movie                              # features/AdMovie.feature:3
    Given I am on the RottenPotatoes home page       # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:44
      Missing template movies/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
        * "/home/ec2-user/environment/01-hw-saas/myrottenpotatoes/app/views"
       (ActionView::MissingTemplate)
      ./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:45:in `/^(?:|I )am on (.+)$/'
      features/AdMovie.feature:4:in `Given I am on the RottenPotatoes home page'
    When I follow "Add new movie"                    # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:56
    Then I should be on the Create New Movie page    # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:230
    When I fill in "Title" with "Men In Black"       # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:60
    And I select "PG-13" from "Rating"               # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:85
    And I press "Save Changes"                       # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:52
    Then I should be on the RottenPotatoes home page # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:230
    And I should see "Men In Black"                  # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:105

Failing Scenarios:
cucumber features/AdMovie.feature:3 # Scenario: Add a movie

1 scenario (1 failed)
8 steps (1 failed, 7 skipped)
0m0.063s
ec2-user:~/environment/01-hw-saas/myrottenpotatoes $
```

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.10'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc


group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', :require => false
  gem 'cucumber-rails-training-wheels' # some pre-fabbed step definitions  
  gem 'database_cleaner' # to clear Cucumber's test database between runs
  gem 'capybara'         # lets Cucumber pretend to be a web browser
  gem 'launchy'         # a useful debugging aid for user stories
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'

  # Use Haml for templates
  gem 'haml'
end
```

Expected cucumber to 'see' .haml files

[workspace + cucumber feature test screenshot here...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XC2M6.png)

Answer (score 0):

In your Gemfile `gem 'haml'` needs to be in your general gems outside of a group.

When cukes runs it runs in the test group.

Putting haml in development and test would be a really bad idea because then all your tests would pass, but as soon as you deployed to production everything would fail.

Comment: Big respect for you @diabolist. Just checking it out... It is pass the test. Buy the way Cucumber daes nothing with 'seeing' .haml, is Capybara's part.